# How to compare two cells in one column and see if they share a common attribute in another column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So, I have a sheet for Customer Data. The Customer Code has a Parent Code column as well. So wherever the Customer Code ought to have a parent code, it does. The parent code which is also a customer in itself will not have this cell filled (Parent X cannot be of Parent X). Now I need to do a validation where the Child Code and Parent Code belong to the same Sub-group.

**Eg:** Parent Code **ABCD** has two Child Codes **ABCD-1** and **ABCD-2** and itself as three line items in total.

The Sheet has over 7000 records, so a pivot table is not working to identify the mismatches. I would need to use some sort of array formula, but I am not sure what is the best way to go about this.

Comment: Can you show a few lines of your data plz with an example of a mismatch as well as a match?

Comment: _Now I need to do a validation where the Child Code and Parent Code belong to the same Sub-group._ I can't stress enough that you need to provide your spreadsheet (or a sample) and this should include an example of a successful outcome. Your description of the spreadsheet and of what a "validation" might be is **ambiguous**.